# pandas loc a single row label and transform the result into a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following `df`,

```
    sequence_num object_id employee_id action_code
0            1    291877        4758     APPROVE
1            0    291877        4758      SUBMIT
2            1    291876        4758     APPROVE
3            0    291876        4758      SUBMIT
```

`df.loc[0]` gave

```
sequence_num    1
object_id       291877
employee_id     4758
action_code     APPROVE   
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

I am wondering how to get above into a DataFrame.

```
    sequence_num object_id employee_id action_code
0            1    291877        4758     APPROVE
```

Comment: what about this `df.head(1)`?

Comment: Use `df.loc[[0]]` or `df.iloc[[0]]` to use integer indexing.